# Observable сервис Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Можно ли в Angular2 сделать observable сервис, который обращался бы к серверу и на выходе давал responce или error? Т.е не observable метод, который шлет обращения к серверу находясь внутри сервиса и затем в компоненте выводит responce или error, а именно, чтобы к сервису можно было обратиться напрямую, применить subscribe и получать из него данные?

Comment: Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Нужен глобальный сервис для всего проекта, который будет обрабатывать\возвращать данные и эти данные через subscribe можно будет вытаскивать в любом компоненте. Но вытаскивать именно обращаясь к сервису, а не к методам внутри него

Comment: Хорошо, а чем методы не угодили? Или вы хотите методы реализовывать "на месте" где будут вызываться?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. Каждый компонент в котором будет вызываться этот глобальный сервис будет реализовывать свои методы.

Comment: Сделайте глобальный класс и от него наследуйте все прочие сервисы. Можно сделать глобальный перехватчик, а для каждого компонента уже реализовывать свой сервис.

Comment: Спасибо большое!